# checkbox concept using angular5 and mongodb

Tags: angular, mongodb

In this code i wrote four interests, for example when user selects 2 interests, the 2 checkbox values are stores in mongodb. I am getting  that saved checkbox values to browser from mongodb successfully. But my problem is to show remaining unchecked checkboxes to browser?

my TS code shows to display checkbox values from mongodb to browser, But i am not able to show unchecked checkboxes in browser.

what i need to write in my query.

Thank you.

> my TS component

```
interests = [
    { value: 'AGING-0', name: 'AGING', id: "1" },
    { value: 'AIDS-1', name: 'AIDS', id: "2" },
    { value: 'ALCOHOLISM-2', name: 'ALCOHOLISM', id: "3" },
    { value: 'ALLERGY-3', name: 'ALLERGY', id: "4" },]
```

> my HTML component

```
        <h5>Please choose your speciality of Interest</h5>
        <div class="interests-list col-md-12">
        <li class="int-list col-md-3"  *ngFor="let interest of editUserDetails.basics[0].interest;let i = index">
              <label>
                      <input type="checkbox"
                             name="interest"
                             value="{{interest}}"        
                             [checked]="editUserDetails.basics[0].interest.indexOf(interest) >= 0"
                             (change)="updateCheckedOptions(interest, $event)"/>
                      {{interest}}
                  </label>  
        </li>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Typescript Code**

```
interests = [
    { value: 'AGING-0', name: 'AGING', id: "1", checked: false },
    { value: 'AIDS-1', name: 'AIDS', id: "2", checked: false },
    { value: 'ALCOHOLISM-2', name: 'ALCOHOLISM', id: "3", checked: false },
    { value: 'ALLERGY-3', name: 'ALLERGY', id: "4", checked: false }];


isCheckBoxCheckedForUser(interest) {
// You can check the 
// editUserDetails.basics[0].interest == interest
// return true or false
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
// you should loop master interests list rather then editUserDetails.basics[0].interest

 <h5>Please choose your speciality of Interest</h5>
        <div class="interests-list col-md-12">
        <li class="int-list col-md-3"  *ngFor="let interest of interests;let i = index">
              <label>
                      <input type="checkbox"
                             name="interest"
                             value="{{interest}}"        
                             [checked]="isCheckBoxCheckedForUser(interest)"
                             (change)="updateCheckedOptions(interest, $event)"/>
                      {{interest}}
                  </label>  
        </li>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a stackblitz which will check for index based on id. Checkbox will mark as checked if it returns true.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qadydh

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: thanks for your reply, But in my ts file i wrote    
                                                    
  isCheckBoxCheckedForUser(seletedcheckbox) {
   var number = this.editUserDetails.basics[0].interest.length;
   for(var i = 1; i <= number; i++){
     if(this.editUserDetails.basics[0].interest === seletedcheckbox){
         console.log('matched');
     }else{
      console.log('unmatched');
     }
 }
    }

Comment: the selected users are not getting into this equation---->this.editUserDetails.basics[0].interest ...  I mean if i select 2values that 2 values are not coming into this condition. how can i do?